# Reinstallation of windows in dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot

I have windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04 as dual OS. I need to reinstall a fresh windows 7 OS.
The boot manager lies on windows partition as windows was the first OS.
Can someone help me in this matter??

Answer (score 0):

1) Install Windows like you would do usually (just don't erase ext3/ext4/swap/Fat32 Ubuntu partitions). This will not harm Ubuntu but will erase Grub and replace it with MBR, so you will only be able to start Windows.

2) Run Ubuntu as a live-cd and reinstall grub on your boot partition :

> See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair for instructions on how to install grub.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install Windows on a system having Ubuntu. There are 2 ways to get it done.
**First, install windows as normal and then,**

1. **Recover the Grub after installing Windows.**
2. **Back up the previous Master Boot Record and Restore it after Windows installation.**

I recommend following the first method since it is a lot easier.

The first method can also be done in different ways such as using a repair disk or by installing the Boot-Repair app in Ubuntu.

1. Download the Boot-Repair disk from the following [link](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/). It is a CD starting Boot-  Repair automatically.
2. Install Boot-Repair in Ubuntu. For that
   [image]

   - connect internet
   - open a new Terminal, then type:

     > sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
   - Press Enter. Then type:

     > > sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
   - Press Enter
   - Done!

Comment: Is that any different than my answer ?

Comment: Try describing the solution than providing a link

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep the windows 8 bootloader, you can just install it normally and use EasyBCD to add the ubuntu bootoption to the windows bootloader

Note if easybcd stops working, go into your program files/ easybcd and copy the .exe, double click the new copy and it works