# Installing Windows 8.1 on an existing dual boot set up

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I'm currently running a Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10 dual boot set up. I want to install a clean Windows 8.1 and maintain my dual boot set up, is it possible? and if it is how can I do it? I need to know the preparation process.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/400536/reinstallation-of-windows-in-dual-boot-system

Comment: so what, you want to be able to boot from ubuntu 13.10 and Windows 8.1. If so just do it normally, windows will overwrite your bootloader, boot into windows, download and run easybcd, click add boot option and click ubuntu

Comment: well, thank you very much for your answer. Yes I do want to do that, I wanted to use GRUB though but it's fine, I can do with Windows boot loader. I'll download easybcd and report the results.

Comment: you can reinstall grub if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Take a backup of important files from the windows 7.
- Run the windows installer,then format the windows7 and install windows 8.1 on the same partition.
- Atlast don't forgot to run [*boot-repair*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).